# How to designate var inside specific HTML element

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="mini-map-pos">x: 17639 / y: 18000</div>
```

the value inside div update every few miliseconds. What a want to do is to get value in front of x:, y: and make it to variable.

```
document.querySelector("#mini-map-pos").textContent (command inside page)
"x: 17817 / y: 18000"(result)
```

so what i want is something like:(var x = 17817(update every milisecond); var y = 18000(update every milisecond);)

Comment: How is the browser supposed to know this is javascript to be executed at all, much less every millisecond?

Comment: `<span>` tags around the numbers.  Update the span innerHTML upon demand

Comment: there aren't span tags around the number.

Comment: Could you add the exact DOM you want to see on-screen after 1 msec, 5msec, ... ?

Comment: I want it to executed every 500 milisecond. If it possible, using setinterval. I think It is not necessary to executed every milisecond.

Comment: @B Aerts Yes I see exact same DOM element after every secs.

Comment: Arent you the one setting the contents of the element after all just do what you need to do at the place you set the values

Comment: Oh i missed it. It works well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you need:

```
var x
var y;

setInterval(function(){ 
    var original_string = document.querySelector("#mini-map-pos").textContent

    var regex = /\d+/g;
    var numbers = original_string .match(regex);

    x = numbers[0];
    y = numbers[1];
    console.log(x+" "+y);
}, 100);
```

Comment: I've edited the answer. That was ```setInterval()```, not ```setTimeout()```. My bad.

Comment: The stackoverflow markdown parser is a odd bird. Either indent the code by four spaces or use fenced code blocks (```) but not both. This also would have been a better answer if you had used  `setTimeout`.